# setenv in Apple Script does not work in Mac OS 10.10 (Yosemite)

Tags: macos, shell, applescript, osx-yosemite

I have a Apple Script Application that I use to set environment variables using several commandos like

```
do shell script "setenv VAR value"
```

But since I updated to Mac OS X 10.10 (Yosemite) this does not work any longer. I get

```
sh: setenv: command not found (127)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could solve it by adding `launchctl` to the line:

```
do shell script "launchctl setenv VAR value"
```

I also had the problem using `nohup` in the same script and had to use the full path `/usr/bin/nohup`instead.